# Getting error like 'Testing1' is not a valid value for AxdEnum_XMLDocPurpose" in AX 2012 r2

Tags: c#, wcf, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012-r2, jitterbit

I am completely new to MS AX technology and recently been allocated to support AX connector which is developed based on .net technologies.

Just to have small intro about AX connector: 
    1. This connector is one that acts as a mediator between AX tool and JB(jitterbit) studio.
    2. Whenever a request(like create/read/update record) issued from JB studio, AX connector takes this 
       request and communicate with AX tool and perform the required operation and gives back respective 
       response back to JB studio.

So, now talking about the issue, a create record request has been issued from JB studio, this particular request is transformed into XML format and received by the AX connector(mediator) and when connector hand over this request to AX tool getting below error:

'Testing1' is not a valid value for AxdEnum_XMLDocPurpose"

**Expectation:**
If request successfully executed/completed, will have 1 record created in MS AX 2012 > CustTable.

**Actual:**
Getting above error or similar error with respect to other field.

**My XML create record Request Below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<Request>
<body>
<executeoperation>
<operation>
<wsdlendpoint>DEMO:8101/.../wsdlendpoint>
<servicename>CustomerServiceClient</servicename>
<name>create</name>
<Parameters xmlns:xsi="">www.w3.org/.../XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:ns3="">schemas.microsoft.com/.../sharedtypes" xmlns:ns2="">schemas.microsoft.com/.../Customer" 
 xmlns:ns1="">schemas.microsoft.com/.../Arrays" xmlns:ns="">schemas.microsoft.com/.../datacontracts">
<CallContext>
<ns:Company>Microsoft</ns:Company>
<ns:Language>Hindi</ns:Language>
<ns:LogonAsUser xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns:MessageId xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns:PartitionKey xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns:PropertyBag xsi:nil="true"/>
</CallContext>

<Customer>
<ns2:SenderId xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:ValidToDateTime timezone="GMTPLUS0530CHENNAI_KOLKATA_MUMBAI" 
 xsi:type="ns3:AxdExtType_CreatedDateTime"/>
<ns2:CustTable>
<ns2:_DocumentHash xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:AccountNum>SH_11285</ns2:AccountNum>
<ns2:AgencyLocationCode xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:BankAccount xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:BankCentralBankPurposeCode xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:BankCentralBankPurposeText xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:BankCustPaymIdTable xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:BirthCountyCode_IT xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:BirthDate_IT>1985-01-12</ns2:BirthDate_IT>
<ns2:BirthPlace_IT>India</ns2:BirthPlace_IT>
<ns2:CashDisc xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:CCMNum_BR xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:ClearingPeriod xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:CNAE_BR xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:CNPJCPFNum_BR xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:CommercialRegister xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:CommercialRegisterInsetNumber xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:CommercialRegisterSection xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:CommissionGroup xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:CompanyChainId xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:CompanyIdSiret xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:CompanyNAFCode xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:ContactPersonId>test@test.com</ns2:ContactPersonId>
<ns2:CreditRating xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:Curp_MX xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:Currency>USD</ns2:Currency>
<ns2:CustClassificationId xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:CustGroup>10</ns2:CustGroup>
<ns2:CustItemGroupId xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:CustTradingPartnerCode xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:DAXIntegrationId xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:DefaultDimension>
<ns3:Values>
<ns3:Value>
<ns3:Name>Rakesh1</ns3:Name>
</ns3:Value>
</ns3:Values>
</ns2:DefaultDimension>
<ns2:DefaultDirectDebitMandate xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:DefaultInventStatusId xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:DestinationCodeId xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:DlvMode xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:DlvReason xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:DlvTerm xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:EinvoiceEANNum xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:EndDisc xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:EnterpriseCode xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:EnterpriseNumber xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:FactoringAccount xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:FederalComments xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:FineCode_BR xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:FiscalCode xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:FreightZone xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:IdentificationNumber xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:IENum_BR xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:INSSCEI_BR xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:IntBank_LV xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:InterestCode_BR xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:InventLocation xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:InventProfileId_RU xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:InventSiteId xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:InvoiceAccount xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:IssuerCountry_HU xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:LineDisc xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:LineOfBusinessId xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:LvPaymTransCodes xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:MainContactPersonnelNumber xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:MainContactWorker xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:MarkupGroup xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:MCRMergedParent xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:MCRMergedRoot xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:Memo xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:MultiLineDisc xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:Name>Shalini1</ns2:Name>
<ns2:NIT_BR xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:numberSequenceGroup xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:OrderEntryDeadlineGroupId xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:OrgId>457848</ns2:OrgId>
<ns2:OurAccountNum xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:PackMaterialFeeLicenseNum xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:Party>Connector</ns2:Party>
<ns2:PartyCountry xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:PartyState xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:PassportNo_HU xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:PaymDayId xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:PaymentReference_EE xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:PaymMode>Credit</ns2:PaymMode>
<ns2:PaymSched xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:PaymSpec xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:PaymTermId xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:PBACustGroupId xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:PdsCustRebateGroupId xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:PdsRebateTMAGroup xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:PriceGroup xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:RegNum_W xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:ResidenceForeignCountryRegionId_IT xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:Rfc_MX xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:SalesCalendarId xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:SalesDistrictId xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:SalesGroup xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:SalesPoolId xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:SegmentId xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:ShipCarrierAccount xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:ShipCarrierAccountCode xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:ShipCarrierId xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:StateInscription_MX xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:StatisticsGroup xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:SubsegmentId xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:SuframaNumber_BR xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:SuppItemGroupId xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:SyncEntityId xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:TaxBorderNumber_FI xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:TaxGroup xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:TaxLicenseNum xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:TaxPeriodPaymentCode_PL xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:TaxWithholdGroup_TH xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:VATNum xsi:nil="true"/>
<ns2:VendAccount xsi:nil="true"/>
</ns2:CustTable>
</Customer>
</Parameters>
</operation>
</executeoperation>
</body>

<authInfo>
<domain>##JB####</domain>
<username>AX2012#######</username>
<password>##########</password>
</authInfo>
<timeoutValue>300</timeoutValue>
</Request>
```

Above request is received in my AX connector and sent to MS AX tool. In the above request there are some mandatory fields like AccountNum, name etc. If I perform create operation with only mandatory fields values, everything works fine. If in case I provide values for non manadatory fields like Company, BirthDate_IT, Party filled in values I am getting below error.

Instance validation error: 'Testing1' is not a valid value for AxdEnum_XMLDocPurpose

Please help me with your ideas. Also plz let me know for pre-requisites, articles to go through understand AX tables, their schemas and valid values for those table fields.

Awaiting your help & suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Rakesh k

Answer (score 3):

The error is straight forward...you're passing bad data somewhere...wherever "Testing1" is being used.

`Testing1` is not valid for the AX enum `XMLDocPurpose`.

If you look in the AOT in AX and find the `XMLDocPurpose` enum located at `\Data Dictionary\Base Enums\XMLDocPurpose` you will see `Testing1` is not valid...unless you've customized `XMLDocPurpose` and added `Testing1`, which I **highly doubt.**

[image]